# Laravel middleware does not work when set as global middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5, middleware

I have a middleware for setting the locale of my laravel application by getting the value from the session before each and every request.

I have a route that sets this variable,and I apply this middleware to all routes,including this one.

Here is my middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App;
use Closure;
use Session;

class LocaleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Session::has('locale')){
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and here is my route for setting the language

```
public function setLang(string $lang)
{
    Session::put('locale', $lang);

    return back();
}
```

Now here is the problem.If I set that middleware to be global,in the kernel file,it does not take effect.The locale is not set properly.

If I manually apply that middleware to every route,it works.

If I assign that middleware to the `web` middleware group,in the kernel file, that is automatically applied to all routes,it works as well.

This confuses me a lot.Please share your advice with me! thanks :)

Comment: Stupid question. Did you add in the middleware array, inside `Kernel.php`?

Comment: post your `kernel.php`

Comment: What did I just say in the question?If I make that middleware global,IN THE KERNEL,it does not work.If I assign the middleware to the web group IN THE KERNEL,it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an answer for that.

The middleware responsible for starting sessions is not a global middleware,it is only in the `web` middleware group.Therefore,laravel was unable to access the session ,since my middleware was run before they were even started.